# Updating datatable when the data changes in a database

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a database that I am reading a reactive table from it. I want the table to update its values when the data changes in the database. I am currently using this but am not satisfied with it. Kindly assist

```
  restock <- reactive({
    invalidateLater(2000,session)
    db <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname="db.sqlite")
    
    data1 <- dbReadTable(db, "restock_df")
  
    data2 <- data1 %>% select(-row_id, -brand, -location , -comment,-date)%>%
      group_by( product) %>% 
      summarise_all(sum)
    
    data2
    
  })
```

Comment: what is the dissatisfaction?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have decided to make it reactive to inputs that do the CRUD operations

```
  restock <- reactive({

### make reactive to inputs example the submit input
    input$submit
    
    data1 <- dbReadTable(db, "restock_df")
  
    data2 <- data1 %>% select(-row_id, -brand, -location , -comment,-date)%>%
      group_by( product) %>% 
      summarise_all(sum)
    
    data2
    
  })
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).